Azure Devops DotNetCoreCLI@2 Test task: How to setup my arguments?
I have a test task like so in my pipeline:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Unit Tests'
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    arguments: '--configuration ${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }} --no-build --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" -- DataCollectionRunSettings.DataCollectors.DataCollector.Configuration.Format=cobertura,opencover'
    publishTestResults: true
    projects: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)\s\$(Build.Repository.Name)\*.sln'

I have multiple test projects that uses XUnit, I want to disable parallelism when running all my unit test in this specific pipeline.
It appears that even though I disabled parallelization in my test projects, the pipeline behaves differently. I saw that it was possible to provide in the arguments the following parameter:
-- xunit.parallelizeAssembly=false

When doing so, the test task fails with the error "One or more runsettings provided contain invalid token". I also tried filtering on a specific test category as a temporary solution, this was done using the documentation given by microsoft https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/main/docs/filter.md. The filtering condition works when done through the cmd, but when using it through the pipeline I still have the same error "One or more runsettings provided contain invalid token".
The filter is added like so in the pipeline:
arguments: '--configuration ${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }} --no-build --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" -- DataCollectionRunSettings.DataCollectors.DataCollector.Configuration.Format=cobertura,opencover --filter TestCategory!=Ignore'

Please help me understand how to setup the arguments.


The filtering condition works when done through the cmd, but when using it through the pipeline I still have the same error "One or more runsettings provided contain invalid token".

I can reproduce the same issue when using the same dotnet task argument.

To solve this issue, you can put the filter category argument after configuration argument.
For example:
arguments: '--configuration release  --filter TestCategory!=Ignore --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" -- DataCollectionRunSettings.DataCollectors.DataCollector.Configuration.Format=cobertura,opencover  -- xunit.parallelizeAssembly=false'

Task YAML:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Unit Tests'
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    arguments: '--configuration ${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }} --filter TestCategory!=Ignore --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" -- DataCollectionRunSettings.DataCollectors.DataCollector.Configuration.Format=cobertura,opencover  -- xunit.parallelizeAssembly=false'
    publishTestResults: true
    projects: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)\s\$(Build.Repository.Name)\*.sln'


My page was not refreshed and I missed your comment ! Thanks for the answer, I managed to find that 8 minutes too late !

Issue found: the --filter TestCategory!=Ignore for example should be place after --configuration ${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }} and not at the end of the arguments.
You should not put any arguments after
--DataCollectionRunSettings.DataCollectors.DataCollector.Configuration.Format=cobertura,opencover

or it will throw (I think if put at the end, the prior argument tries to parse the filter and it throws).
